# Ruby > Psych -> How to parse yaml docs in to ruby objects

Tags: ruby, yaml, psych

I'm trying to do the following:

- open and read a file with multiple yaml docs
- parse yaml docs into ruby objects
- print content of each ruby object

and the code:

```
yml_string = Psych.dump(File.read(infile))
Psych.load_stream(yml_string) .each do |mobj|
  puts "mobj:\n #{mobj}"
end
```

The puts prints the contents of the yml_string (multiple yaml docs) but it is one long string. How does one go about parsing each yaml doc from the yml_string and store them in to ruby objects?

The contents of infile (based on OP's comment):

```
---
member:
    country: AF
    phone1: 60 223-4564
    phone2: +93 799 123-456

---
member:
    country: BR
    phone1: +55 55 2000 3456
    phone2: 55 9000 1234

---
member:
    country: CA
    phone1: 604 423-4567
    phone2: +1 604 423-4567
```

Comment: The infile file content would look something like this:

    ---
    member:
        country: AF
        phone1: 60 223-4564
        phone2: +93 799 123-456
    ---
    member:
        country: BR
        phone1: +55 55 2000 3456
        phone2: 55 9000 1234
    ---
    member:
        country: CA
        phone1: 604 423-4567
        phone2: +1 604 423-4567

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up with

```
yaml_hash = Psych.load_stream(File.read(infile))
yaml_hash.each do |member|
  mem = Hash[member['member']]
end
```

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: for me, on ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-darwin16] i had to use: mem = Hash[member]['member']

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'yaml'
require 'pp'

infile = "test.yml"

pp YAML.load_stream(File.read(infile))
# [{"member"=>
#    {"country"=>"AF", "phone1"=>"60 223-4564", "phone2"=>"+93 799 123-456"}},
#  {"member"=>
#    {"country"=>"BR", "phone1"=>"+55 55 2000 3456", "phone2"=>"55 9000 1234"}},
#  {"member"=>
#    {"country"=>"CA", "phone1"=>"604 423-4567", "phone2"=>"+1 604 423-4567"}}]
```

On recent MRI psych is the same as yaml lib

```
p [RUBY_VERSION, YAML == Psych]
["2.0.0", true]
p [RUBY_VERSION, YAML == Psych]
["1.9.3", true]
```

Comment: Thank you avsej for your response; however, the second part of the question is still unanswered - parse yaml docs into ruby objects? To put in another way, how would you create ruby objects to contain 'member' data?

Comment: Sorry I did not get it. The hash `{"country"=>"AF", "phone1"=>"60 223-4564", "phone2"=>"+93 799 123-456"}` is a ruby object, isn't it?